# Why is the complement operator not working when bool = true?

Tags: c++, boolean, complement

I have written this C++ program, and I am not able to understand why it is printing `1` in the third `cout` statement.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool b = false;
    cout << b << "\n";  // Print 0
    b = ~b;
    cout << b << "\n"; // Print 1
    b = ~b;
    cout << b << "\n"; // Print 1 **Why?**
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
```

Why is it not printing the following?

```
0
1
0
```

Comment: Really dont know why someone voting to close.

Comment: +1 @vikiiii - Unfortunately, downvoting and voting to close are the weak points of stackexchange, I believe because they happen in an anonymous manner.

Comment: So you basically use the wrong operator and wondering why it gives you not what you expected?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is due to C legacy operator mechanization (also recalling that `~` is *bitwise* complement). Integral operands to `~` are promoted to int before doing the operation, then converted back to `bool`. So effectively what you're getting is (using unsigned 32 bit representation) `false` -> `0` -> `0xFFFFFFFF` -> `true`. Then `true` -> `1` -> `0xFFFFFFFE` -> `1` -> `true`.

You're looking for the `!` operator to invert a boolean value.

Comment: Because false is represented as `0x0000` using unsigned int, while true can be anything else.

Answer (score 7):

You probably want to do this:

```
b = !b;
```

which is logical negation. What you did is bitwise negation of a `bool` cast to an integer. The second time the statement `b = ~b;` is executed, the prior value of `b` is `true`. Cast to an integer this gives `1` whose bitwise complement is `-2` and hence cast back to bool `true`. Therefore, `true` values of `b` will remain `true` while `false` values will be assigned `true`. This is due to the C legacy.

Answer (score 7):

As pretty much everyone else has said, the bool is getting promoted to an integer before the complement operator is getting its work done.  ~ is a bitwise operator and thus inverts each individual bit of the integer; if you apply ~ to 00000001, the result is 11111110.  When you apply this to a 32-bit signed integer, ~1 gives you -2.  If you're confused why, just take a look at a binary converter.  For example: http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_int.html?decimal=045050

To your revised question:

False to true works for the same reason as above.  If you flip 00000000 (out to 32 bits), you get 11111111... which I believe is -1 in integer.  When comparing boolean values, anything that is -not- 0 is considered to be true, while 0 alone is false.

Answer (score 2):

You should use logical operators, not binary operators. Use `!` instead of `~`.